# Edit Wordpress invite email on network/multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

How do I edit the invite emails that a wordpress multisite sends out when inviting a new user to join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`wpmu_signup_user_notification_email`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_signup_user_notification_email/) and [`wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject/) filters to replace the message content and the subject.

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_subject', 'my_activation_email_subject', 10, 1 );
function my_activation_email_subject($subject) {
    // return your subject
}

add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'my_activation_email_message', 10, 4);
function my_activation_email_message($message, $user, $user_email, $key) {
    // return your template
}
```

Comment: Hi Vard, thank you for your answer, but this is apparently not the right email. I have a multisite, and when I add a user, they get a slightly different email: "You've been invited to join 'Site Name' at" etc... I can't find that specific function that sends this email.

Comment: Well it should be the `wpmu_signup_user_notification_email` filter (see [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_created_user_email/) - you can see the message you're talking about in the source). If the filter doesn't work try to change the priority to 11.